# How to request an abbreviated http header

Tags: apache, http, embedded

I'm working with a WiFi connected micro-controller.  I am interacting with an API that is hosted on an Apache server.  I have very limited RAM on the client.  It's a value line(*read: cheap*) micro-conroller and only has 4KB of RAM. The HTTP header sometimes takes up 500 bytes all by itself.  The payload is just a few dozen bytes of JSON.  A lot of the header information contained in the HTTP header is useless to me, I only really need `Content-Length`.  So, I'm wasting a lot of my RAM on buffers that have to be large enough to hold all this wasted HTTP info.

Is there a way to request that the server send less header content in requests?

Comment: Is the Apache server proxying your device?

Comment: @DKrueger I don't know everything about what the server is doing, but there are not proxies that I'm aware of.

Comment: I usee. Your device is sending requests to the Apache server and you have no control of that server. I think you're out of luck in that case. Is there any way to parse the header on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to keep the entire HTTP header in RAM. You should try and read one line at a time. The http header fields have a simple "key: value\r\n" pattern (except for the first line).
When you receive the stream of bytes, store all characters until you receive the \r\n pattern. Then parse that line, clear the buffer and start receiving the following bytes. On so on...
You'll find that the buffer you really need is not very large.